# Storing a register form array in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, local-storage, forms-authentication

I found this **register** form that store `username` and `password` in the **localstorage**, but as you see it can store hypothetically only one account and so when you log in you can only use the latest data that has been registered. My aim is to store lots of usernames and passwords in localstorage, I think using an array, but I am not really sure how to do it and then also how to check in this hypothetically array for the the match with the data of login form.
Down the obviously wrong code I tried to write.

This is the html and javascript for the register form.

```
<html>
    <form id="register-form"> 
        <input id="nome" type="text" placeholder="Name" value=""/>
        <input id="pw" type="password" placeholder="Password" value=""/>
        <input id="rgstr_btn" type="submit" value="get Account" onClick="store()"/> 
    </form>
</html>

<script>

    // Name and Password from the register-form
    var nome = [];
    var pw = [];
    var i=0;
    nome[i] = document.getElementById('nome');
    pw[i] = document.getElementById('pw');

    // storing input from register-form
    function store() {
        localStorage.setItem('nome', JSON.stringify(nome));
        localStorage.setItem('pw', JSON.stringify(pw));
        i++;
    }
</script>
```

And this is the html and javascript for login form.

```
<html>
    <form id="login-form"> 
        <input id="userName" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" value=""/>
        <input id="userPw" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" value=""/>
        <input id="login_btn" type="submit" value="Login" onClick="check()"/> 
    </form>
</html>

<script>
    // entered data from the login-form
    var userName = document.getElementById('userName');
    var userPw = document.getElementById('userPw');

    // check if stored data from register-form is equal to data from login form
    // stored data from the register-form
    for(i=0;i<nome.length;i++){
        var storedName = [];
        var storedPw = [];
        storedName[i]=localStorage.getItem('nome[i]');
        storedPw[i]=localStorage.getItem('pw[i]');
        if(userName.value == storedName[i] && userPw.value == storedPw[i]) {
            alert('You are loged in.');
        }else {
            alert('ERROR.');
        }
    }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a practical use for this scenario, however you can modify the store() function to allow for adding multiple values by using 'name' as the key and 'pw' as the value:

```
function store() {
  localStorage.setItem(name, pw);
}
```

Then retrieval

```
var user = localStorage.getItem(userName);
if (user === userPw) {
      alert('You are logged in.');
}else {
    alert('ERROR.');
}
```

Your alternative is to insert an array into localStorage, then the only way to add a value to it would be to retrieve the array, push a new value to it then re-add the array to localStorage.

Comment: Ok i get your idea of storing names as keys and passwords as values but i don't think you can retrive them with your method because if you have multiple keys and values stored it doesn't search for every lines. I tried it and it doesn't work so i think that i have to use a for cicle that compare all the values from the login form with the stored values but i am not sure how to do it